# set default view for date/time input field, overriding user locale?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, datepicker

I am rendering a datepicker within a Django Form. The answer may apply more to JS and HTML, but I'm being specific.

```
date_field= forms.DateField(
    input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
    widget=forms.DateInput(    
        format='%Y-%m-%d', 
        attrs={'type': 'date'} 
    )
)
```

This renders my form and all, but unfortunately, the datepicker display field itself conforms to my US locale:

[image]

Is it possible to preset the default display to something like 2020-11-13?

Comment: Did you mean ***default value***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by changing the widget DateInput type to text:

```
date_field = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d'],
        widget=forms.DateInput(    
            format='%Y-%m-%d', 
            attrs={'type': 'text'} 
        )
    )
```

This renders a blank form, but that is fine for my purposes as clicking on it still pops open the datepicker.